# Delete Small Folders Under 50 MB With Spaces in Name

Tags: command-line, directory, delete, find

How do I delete all folders in a directory that are under 50 MB total in size?  The directories have spaces and special characters in their names, but no line feeds.  There could be sub-directories inside the directories, so I just need the size of the first level directories and looking for less than 50 MB total in size.

```
Directory Example:
/test
--/test/Example
--/test/Example 2
--/test/Sample Directory Inside (2018)
--/test/Sample & Test Directory
--/test/Sample/Inside Directory
```

It should find all directories in the /test location under 50 MB in size and delete that directory.  Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-liner using `find`:

```
find /test -mindepth 1 -type d -prune \
  -exec sh -c '[ $(du -s "$1" | awk "{print \$1}") -lt 50000 ] && echo rm -Rf "$1"' _ {} \;
```

Remove the `echo` in front of `rm` if it works for you.

**Explanation:**

- `find /test -mindepth 1 -type d -prune` find all directories in /test (and don't decend into directories that get deleted).
- `-exec sh -c 'cmd "$1"' _ {} \;` run `cmd` with path to folder (`{}`) as argument `$1`.
- `[ $(du -s "$1" | awk "{print \$1}") -lt 50000 ] && rm -Rf "$1"` Check the size of the directory and remove if smaller than 50.000 byte (50M).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple Bash script that uses the command `du` to get the directory size:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

TARGET_DIR="/test"

# For each sub dir in $TARGET_DIR
for dir in "$TARGET_DIR"/*/
do
    # If the result of the command substitution $(...) is lower or equal to 50000
    if [[ $(du -s "$dir" | awk '{print $1}') -le 50000 ]]
    then
        # Do (remove `echo' to apply the action):
        echo rm -rf "$dir"
    fi
done
```

- What the command substitution does is:

  - `du -s` - display only a total for each argument.
  - `|` - pipe the output of the previous to stdin of the next command
  - `awk '{print $1}'` - will output only the first field
- Alternatively you can use arithmetical expression:

  ```bsh
  if (( "$(du -s "$dir" | awk '{print $1}')" <= 50000 )); then rm -rf "$dir"; fi
  ```
- You can play also with the `du` options: for example add `-m` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17599214/6543935)) and modify the condition:

  ```bsh
  if (( "$(du -sm "$dir" | awk '{print $1}')" <= 50 )); then rm -rf "$dir"; fi
  ```
- The previous version of the answer: https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1073858/2

Comment: If you do `"$TARGET_DIR"/*/` with a trailing slash, you can get just the directories and omit the `-d` check.

Comment: Thanks for this simplification, @muru. I've updated the answer.